# "Unless someone lives under a rock"

Tags: phrases

Could the expression *unless someone lives under a rock* be used in a formal setting? If no, what are some alternatives that could be used instead?

Comment: There is an implied insult (presumably of 3rd parties) which makes it improper for formal use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is a kind of extended comment on Kosmonaut's answer. I would have said that "unless you live under a rock" tends to be used with situations where the person who lives under the rock is out of touch with current events. Googling for the phrase gives things like

> Unless you live under a rock, you’re more than aware about the Federal Election Campaign that’s currently taking place.
>
> Unless you live under a rock, you’ve heard the word blog used sometime
>   in the last couple of years
>
> Unless you live under a rock, you probably have been inundated with news of the upcoming iPhone 3GS.
>
> Unless you live under a rock, you may have heard that starlet Lindsay Lohan is in a little bit of trouble.

etc. It's not used so much with things like "circles are round".

> Could the expression in the title be
>   used in a formal setting? If no, what
>   are some alternatives that could be
>   used instead?

I'm not sure how to answer the question you posed since I don't know exactly what "in a formal setting" means.

You want alternatives?

> Unless you are totally out of touch with the real world
>
> Unless you never read a newspaper
>
> Unless you have been lost in the Himalayas

etc. I could easily go on all night.

Comment: What about:
"Nowadays, [...] has been starring as a central story in the news due to... "?

Comment: @myle: there are millions of possibilities if you want to get started.

Answer (score 6):

You would probably not use this in a formal setting, but that is probably due to the fact that it would be considered rude.  The problem with suggesting a formal alternative is that the sentiment itself is rude.

> Unless you live under a rock, you know that circles are round. (=unless you are totally ignorant!)

Some formal alternatives might therefore be things like:

> - It should be quite obvious that circles are round.
> - It goes without saying that circles are round.
> - It is a well-known fact that circles are round.

Comment: Hm, I don't think it's used with "circles are round" sorts of phrases.

Comment: @Shinto: perhaps, but in this case, that doesn't have a bearing on the question being answered here.

Comment: @Steve: I think it is relevant.  In a formal setting you might say "Unless you're living under a rock, you may have heard of Paris Hilton."  In this case, it's not rude; someone who doesn't follow pop culture may have been so fortunate without being an idiot.

Comment: Jeez, why is everybody so caught up on the "circles are round" part?  I just included that in order to have a complete sentence.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: the meaning you've given the phrase is "unless you are totally ignorant" and used this to claim that the sentiment is rude, hence the answer I posted (which is a comment on your answer, as I noted). That isn't OK, I don't think. I don't think anyone is specifically commenting on the "circles are round" but that whole sort of phrase.

Comment: I do think your emphasis on current events gets to the heart of the idiom better than my answer. But, I do still think that calling someone out of touch is rude in a formal setting.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some alternatives that could help you:

- unless you've been living under a rock
- unless you've been living in a cave
- unless you've totally been in no contact with the real world
- unless you've been in some fantasy world where everything goes perfect

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance.